# When downloading file, its size is 0 bytes

Tags: php, file, download

When I try to download a file, it downloads but without content, i.e., its size is 0 bytes.
I am using this code, what I am doing wrong?

```
$fullPath = "/home/yakar/www/files/gpx/".$file;

if (file_exists($fullPath)) {


    // setting headers
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
    die('File does not exist');
}
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: if `$file` is not in the current directory, maybe change to `readfile($fullPath)` ?

Comment: @Alex2php, that worked. Maybe put your comment as an answer?